# Create clickable Images in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, nativescript

I am looking for a way to set clickable images in NativeScript. I plan to set 5 images next to each others and whenever one image is clicked the images to the left should change its their values.

What I tried:

```
    <Label col="0" row="0" class="text-details segment-content" [text]="'RATING_AVG'|translate">
    </Label>
    <Label col="1" row="0" class="text-details segment-content">
        <GridLayout columns="*,*,*,*,*" rows="*">
            <Image src="~/pages/filmdetails/Stern-outline-10.jpg" col="0" row="0">
                <Button (onTap)="logTap()">
                </Button>
            </Image>
            <Image src="~/pages/filmdetails/Stern-outline-10.jpg" col="1" row="0">
                <Button (onTap)="logTap()">
                </Button>
            </Image>
            <Image src="~/pages/filmdetails/Stern-outline-10.jpg" col="2" row="0">
                <Button (onTap)="logTap()">
                </Button>
            </Image>
            <Image src="~/pages/filmdetails/Stern-outline-10.jpg" col="3" row="0">
                <Button (onTap)="logTap()">
                </Button>
            </Image>
            <Image src="~/pages/filmdetails/Stern-outline-10.jpg" col="4" row="0">
                <Button (onTap)="logTap()">
                </Button>
            </Image>
        </GridLayout>   
    </Label>
```

Which did not even display the images. What did I do wrong?

Edit: Updated formatting

Comment: I've never used nativescript but the nesting looks off. You have a `Gridlayout` inside a `Label`, and three of your `Image`s aren't inside the five column `Gridlayout`.

Comment: And according to [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/button.html) it's supposed to be `<Button (tap)="logTap()">`

Comment: Oh I missed some formatting obviously at that images - the onTap function works, I already tested that with another Button. But thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you can set a `touch` listener simply using the `on("event", implementation)` method.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures#touch

Therefore your images would have a `(tap)` attribute in xml, or you can set the onTap event as mentioned above.

And `Image` is not a composite view (a layout), therefore it should not hold a button element within.